# Where 'foo' OR 'bar' AND 'lol' OR 'rofl' MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, operator-precedence

In what order would this be evaluated. My intension is that if it finds either foo or bar, it would also search for lol and rofl.
Is this totally in the woods? And if so, how would one evaluate an expression like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `AND` operator has higher precedence than `OR` in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html), so your current expression evaluates as:

```
WHERE 'foo' OR ('bar' AND 'lol') OR 'rofl'
```

Add parentheses to the expression if you want to force the evaluation order:

```
WHERE ('foo' OR 'bar') AND ('lol' OR 'rofl')
```

Comment: Very much appriciated. Was under the impression that OR had higher priority. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`AND` will be processed first, after that `OR` will be processed. So, it will be:

```
'foo' OR ('bar' AND 'lol') OR 'rofl'
```

After that, it is *left to right* order.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) - AND has a higher precedence, so it would be like this:

```
WHERE 'foo' OR ( 'bar' AND 'lol' ) OR 'rofl'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Id, Name
FROM
  TestTable
WHERE
    (Name = 'foo') OR (Name = 'bar') AND (Name = 'lol') OR (Name = 'rofl')
```

Will give you the following result in MS SQL Server:

```
1 foo
4 rofl
```

So it seems it will combine bar AND lol and evals foo and rofl seperately like this:

```
SELECT
      Id, Name
    FROM
      TestTable
    WHERE
        (Name = 'foo') OR ((Name = 'bar') AND (Name = 'lol')) OR (Name = 'rofl')
```

What you probably want to do is (technically):

```
SELECT
      Id, Name
    FROM
      TestTable
    WHERE
        ((Name = 'foo') OR (Name = 'bar')) AND ((Name = 'lol') OR (Name = 'rofl'))
```