# Query to return all records if parameter value is null

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, isnull

```
SELECT g.date,g.description,g.amount AS cash,0 AS cheque FROM generalledger AS g WHERE g.type="cash" AND g.date=?
UNION ALL
SELECT gg.date,gg.description,0 AS cash, gg.amount AS cheque FROM generalledger AS gg WHERE gg.type="cheque" AND gg.date=?
```

I've this query I want to check if g.date's & gg.date's parameter value is null then return all the records other wise only return records according to the parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
AND (g.date=? or ? is null)
```

Comment: I would make one suggestion in that which ever case is more common (variable provided or not) should be evaluated first, its a relatively small performance save until you start talking about millions of rows, then it starts to add up.

Comment: Being more left in a query is no garantee of being evaluated first. The compiler does that unpredictable when it optimizes the query.

Comment: Oh, that is good to know. If it were a real concern would it be possible to restructure it to force one to evaluate first, or does the optimizer ignore any type of precedence structuring?

Comment: I currently don't know any way to influence that. But maybe there is. I have not needed that til now.

Comment: SET gdate :="";

SELECT g.date,g.description,g.amount AS cash,0 AS cheque FROM generalledger AS g WHERE g.type="cash" AND (g.date=gdate or gdate is null)
UNION ALL
SELECT gg.date,gg.description,0 AS cash, gg.amount AS cheque FROM generalledger AS gg WHERE gg.type="cheque" AND (gg.date=gdate or gdate is null)

I've tried this query but no luck! am I missing something?

Comment: oops! sorry! it was '', I've changed the value to null, its working

Comment: @juergend Just to provide some closure I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266346/where-foo-or-bar-and-lol-or-rofl-mysql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated this would lead me to believe  wrapping the is null check in parentheses would force it to evaluate first.